# How to use user input with an existing variable

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm trying to write a script where the list choice is configurable with the for loop:

```
list1="name1 name2"
list2="name3 name4"

echo "which list do you want to use? (list1 or list2)"
read userInput

for item in $userInput
do ....
```

This isn't working. I also tried this below, but no luck either.

```
for item in $($userInput)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indirect parameter expansion:

```
for item in ${!userInput} ; do
    ...
done
```

You should validate $userInput before running the loop, though.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem. And I do have input validation, I just removed it to simplify the question. :)

Comment: More information about indirection that I looked up: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection

Answer (score 0):

It does work, just don't use the `for item in` loop. That works for arrays. What you have read into $userInput is a string. Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

list1="name1 name2"
list2="name3 name4"

echo "which list do you want to use? (list1 or list2)"
read userInput

if [ $userInput == "list2" ] ;
then
    something
else
    something else
fi
```

Obviously, change "something" and "something else" to whatever your script needs to do.

Comment: Please use @choroba's answer, much more elegant.